# How can I use Top Navigator and Bottom Navigator without having Top Navigator overlap with the Status Bar in React Navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, statusbar, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I am trying to nest a top navigator within a bottom navigator in react navigation. However when I do that, the top navigator collides with the status bar. I'm assuming it's because the bottom navigator is pushing it up. But how can I make it so both navigators show up, alongside the status bar? Below is an image of the overlapping issue. I'm using react navigation 5 and any other solution uses older versions which I've tried and don't work.

By the way I'm coding this on an iPhone 11 if that info is needed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should set your app container styles to have a `marginTop` value equal to the status bar height. Then your whole app will show below the status bar.

Something like this:

```
import Constants from "expo-constants";

...

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried adding that to the navigation container but it doesn't work. with react navigation 5 it doesn't use appContainer and I'm using functional components like it the new documentation shows, not sure if that's why it wont work or not?

Comment: wait actually I added it to the createMaterialTopTabNavigator.Navigator and it worked there! thank youo